# App generated using 'Generate Signed APK' is Buggy/Has Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

First things first: problem is not the generating APK, since I do not get errors building APK using "Generate Signed APK" of Android Studio.

- Proguard is enabled i.e. `minifyEnabled true`
- Suppressed the warnings and issues coming from ProGuard specifically with the Picasso library, since I used Picasso in my project
- I added this in my ProGuard file. `-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**`
- the keystore has no issues whatsoever
- Using `JavascriptInterface` methods

My problem is the app itself at runtime. Comparing from the debug app, a portion of the generated app seems problematic. Specific problem is, when going to a next activity, it doesnt proceed i.e. using `startActivity(Intent)`, but no crash, doesn't force close though. And no errors are generated because of this and I have no idea. Seems bizarre. Maybe some of you guys experienced this after building APK from 'Generate Signed APK'.

What can I possibly do to fix this issue? What kind of issues am I having?

EDIT: I stated using `JavascriptInterface` methods, and as of now, I'm tracing the error rooting from the `JavascriptInterface` method calls.

Comment: is it a force close? no logcat msg?

Comment: may be due to proguard.some method might not be found...check if this has been added -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** in your proguard config.

Comment: @Hardik Amal i added that to my proguard file. i'll update question

Comment: @fatboy no force close, no log in logcat, it silently doesnt continue to another activity

Comment: Can you add a log message on both sides of the intent firing to see if anything is happening?

Comment: Have you added android specifiic rules to your proguard file? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication

Comment: @TamásKozmér i've added android specific proguard now.

Comment: As of now, I have traced the error rooting from `JavascriptInterface` not from `startActivity()`

Comment: try to build apk without pro guard and check if problem exist or not..